# Employer breach of data protection act?

Tags: professionalism, united-kingdom

I work  as a mental health support worker in a residential home.

The service manager has given my home telephone number to a resident's family member and the family member has left a message on my home landline number.

I feel that my privacy has been compromised and I am wondering what to do about it.  The service manager has emailed me to admit what they have done and apologise.  However, I had previously resigned two weeks ago and was already off of work with stress due to workplace intimidation by co-workers.

Should I report this matter to the ICO (Information Commissioner's Office) or perhaps the Care Quality Commission?  The company deals with very vulnerable people and their confidential details, if a service manager is allowed to breach my confidentiality, then it could also be done to a service user.

Comment: A lot of stuff *can* happen.

Comment: Do you really not understand the potential and actual damage that can come from the family of a patient having personal contact information of ex-staff, which they were not legally permitted to be given access?

Answer (score 14):

The manager in question e-mailed you to admit fault and apologize (on their own initiative, from the way you tell it here.)  That shows that they know what they did was wrong and have presumably learned a lesson from it.  My impression is that they probably won't do it again.

The question, then, is how interested are you in ruining this person's life?  How invested are you in following this to its logical conclusion, if the ICO or CQC decide to take legal action?

Yes, this person wronged you.  Yes, that has caused you grief.  But do you really want justice, or do you just want revenge?  I don't think there's much to be gained from reporting this person.  Having admitted their mistake, their own conscience should help prevent them from doing it again.  We err; we learn; we improve.  If you report them and get them fired, they may get replaced by someone new who doesn't give two whiffs about giving out this sort of information, and ultimately nothing gets better.

Personally, I would just let it go.

Comment: @Paparazzi The UK Data Protection Act covers confidential employee information, too - the ex-employer has made a breach and Steve-O's answer is a good one.

Comment: This is a good answer. There is almost no potential for further infringement here, so the only question left to ask is: Will you throw the book at this clearly remorseful manager? If so, why?

Comment: @Magisch well the OP says they resigned due to bullying by coworkers so maybe the manger does have something to answer for